# How to remove unnecessary "and" in inflect num to words python package

Tags: python

I'm using the python package `inflect` to convert numbers to words. I would like to know how I can have `inflect` convert the numbers the right way without unnecessary "and" in the end result.

Here's my code

```
from datetime import date
import inflect, sys
def main():
    print(time_check(input("What's your DOB?: ")))

def time_check(check):
    p = inflect.engine()
    year, month, day = check.split("-")
    year, month, day = int(year), int(month), int(day)
    dob = date(year, month, day)
    diff = date.today() - dob

    # Convert days to minutes & then use inflect to convert the number to words
    ans = p.number_to_words(diff.days*24*60)
    return f"{ans.capitalize()} minutes"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I input `"2021-10-10"` as my Date of Birth(DOB), `ans` will become

```
ans = p.number_to_words(525,600)
```

This will then print "Five hundred and twenty five-thousand, six hundred minutes" but I don't want that as that is partially incorrect.
I want my code to print **"Five hundred twenty five-thousand, six hundred minutes"** without the "and".

I know I can use the `replace` method to replace the "and" with an empty string, but I don't want to do that. I want the `inflect` python package to convert numbers to words using this right way.

I hope you guys can understand the problem here & hope to get your help.

Comment: What's wrong with your `.replace` method? Or, in fact just leaving it as it is?

Comment: [Read the source or the documentation](https://github.com/jaraco/inflect/blob/1f34464ae27f5a8a16a1de667ed544cff30e261b/inflect/__init__.py#L3799), maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `andword` in `number_to_words()` as it is 'and' by default. See the [inflect documentation](https://inflect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#inflect.engine.number_to_words) for more details.

```
p.number_to_words(diff.days*24*60, andword = '')
```

This will print the following directly (for 2021-10-10):

```
Five hundred twenty-five thousand, six hundred minutes
```